# Why did I use AnimatedVisibility as a deletion animation in LazyColumn without any effect

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun <T> SwipeRefreshLazyColumn(
    data: List<T>?,
    dataStatus: DataStatus,
    isNavVisible: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(true),
    onRefresh: () -> Unit,
    onLoadMore: () -> Unit,
    onReload: () -> Unit,
    isHaveHead: Boolean = false,
    head: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable (index: Int, item: T) -> Unit
) {
    ...

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.bgColorSecondary)),
                state = lazyListState,
            ) {
                ...
                if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    itemsIndexed(data) { index: Int, item: T ->
                        key(item) {
                            AnimatedVisibility(
                                visible = data.contains(item),
                                enter = expandVertically(),
                                exit = shrinkHorizontally(
                                    animationSpec = tween(500)
                                )
                            ) {
                                Surface(elevation = 1.dp) {
                                    Column(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
                                    ) {
                                        Surface(elevation = 1.dp) {
                                            content(index, item)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                }
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}

fun unCollect(id: Int) {
        launch(
            block = {
                mRespository.unCollect(id)
                UserManager.removeCollectId(id)
                val index = articleList.value.indexOfFirst { it.originId == id  }
                articleList.value.removeAt(index)
                Bus.post(USER_COLLECT_UPDATE, id to false)
            }
        )
    }
```

Why did I use AnimatedVisibility as a deletion animation in LazyColumn without any effect
In the viewmodel of a page, I removed a data item from the articleList, but there was no animation effect
I would like to know how to modify the code to see the deleted animation effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwipeToDismiss inside LazyColumn with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066048/swipetodismiss-inside-lazycolumn-with-animation)