# How to add animation on view pager (accompanist library) on button click in jetpack compose Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to add animation like slide in / slide out when a cross button is clicked on the card of horizontal pager and want to show remove it with some animation . I was able to remove it but want to show animation when removed.

Comment: Have you checked [Compose Animation Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility)?

Comment: Doesn't work properly

Comment: This comment does not help me help you. What code did you try, how did you expect it to work, and how did it actually work? Please update your question by adding this information

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834907/13372186

Comment: @hahmraro  I want to use animation effect in horizontal pager.